# Squarespace: Adding a jquery plugin on a blog post

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, squarespace

I'm trying to add the elevateZoom jquery plugin (https://www.elevateweb.co.uk/image-zoom/) to my site. I'm then trying to call it for a specific image on this page: https://www.meridianacademy.org/division3-humanities/2020/5/6/civil-rights-quilt.

I've uploaded the plugin as a link and added it to my site's head via code injection.

I then called it on the page via a codeblock:

```
<script>
$(document).on('ready', function () {
    $("#block-yui_3_17_2_1_1588791147485_100779").elevateZoom({
zoomType: "inner",
cursor: "crosshair",
zoomWindowFadeIn: 500,
zoomWindowFadeOut: 750
   }); 
});
</script>
```

But it does not seem to be working. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: There are a few issues teaming up on you here. To help provide a solid answer, could you say 1) whether you are using (or might use) JQuery elsewhere on the site or just on that page and 2) whether you are using (or might use) ElevateZoom on other pages or just that page in particular?

Comment: @Brandon I am using JQuery elsewhere on the site and might add more in the future. And yes, I might end up using ElevateZoom on other pages as well if I can get it to work. Thanks for looking at the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like have 4 potential problems working against you on this.

1. The script `/s/jqueryelevateZoom-308min.js` isn't loading due to Squarespace responding with the `Content-Disposition: Attachement` header. I suppose that is just how Squarespace is setup for assets in the /s/ folder. That didn't used to be the case, but it appears to be now.
2. The on ready JQuery event may not fire at the proper time.
3. The source image that will be zoomed may not be large enough, due to Squarespace's JavaScript-based dynamic image loader.
4. You should target the `img` element inside that image block div, not just the image block div itself.

To remedy all of those issues, do the following:

In the header code injection, replace the line `<script src="/s/jqueryelevateZoom-308min.js"></script>` with the actual contents of the `jqueryelevateZoom-308min.js` file, pasted between an opening and closing `<script>` tag. So it'd look like this:

```
<!-- Plugin elevateZoom -->
<script>
window.Squarespace.onInitialize(Y, function() {
// copy and paste contents of the script here
});
</script>
<!-- end Plugin elevateZoom -->
```

Then, add the following script below that.

```
<!-- Initialize elevateZoom -->
<script>
window.Squarespace.onInitialize(Y, function() {
  var eZImgs = [
    {
      selector: "#block-yui_3_17_2_1_1588791147485_100779 img",
      settings: {
        zoomType: "inner",
        cursor: "crosshair",
        zoomWindowFadeIn: 500,
        zoomWindowFadeOut: 750
      }
    } // Add more comma-separated objects after this object to init elevateZoom on other images on the site.
  ];
  var i = eZImgs.length;
  var el;
  while (i--) {
    el = $(eZImgs[i].selector);
    if (el) {
      el.attr("src", el.attr("src").replace(/\?format\=.*w$/, "?format=original"));  // Load the original image, not the dynamically-loaded, smaller image.
      el.elevateZoom(eZImgs[i].settings);
    }
  }
});
<script>
<!-- end initialize elevateZoom -->
```

Finally, remove the code from the code block that you previously added.

Comment: I've made all those adjustments but it still doesn't seem to firing correctly. Any additional thoughts? The console does not seem to identify "el.elevateZoom" as a function.

Comment: Interesting. It works when copy/pasted in console after your site loads. So, it's just a matter of timing. Two ideas: 1) See the update to the first code snippet above that has been wrapped in a Squarespace onInit function. Try that, and if that doesn't work, then try 2) Remove the first and last line of each code snippet (that is, unwrap the code from within squarespace.onInit function) and move both snippets to the Footer code injection area instead of Header code injection. You can leave the JQuery script in the header.

Comment: Adding the Squarespace onInit function did it--thanks, Brandon!